# Create a individual custom post type taxonomy Archive Page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently using archive.php as a generic listing for categories, tags, authors, etc. My theme have 4 custom post type and i want each post type have separate archive template.

How to add separate archive template for each custom post type?

I have a code but not working is there i m missing some thing?

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'wpsites_cpt_archive_page_template', 99 );

 function wpsites_cpt_archive_page_template( $template ) {

if ( is_post_type_archive(array( first-post-type ) ) ) {
    $new_template = locate_template( array( 'your-cpt-template.php' ) );
    if ( '' != $new_template ) {
        return $new_template ;
    }
}

return $template;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

checkout wordpress [template files](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/) docs,

you don't need to use conditionals for separating post type template,

you can simply create `archive-{your-post-type}.php` file to have different archive template for each post type.

for taxonomy;

```
taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php
taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php
tag-{slug}.php
tag-{id}.php
category-{slug}.php
category-{ID}.php
```

Additionally, if your theme supports standard loop hooks like Genesis Framework, You can use conditional to build custom loop depending on Post type.

Comment: i already add 'archive-{your-post-type}.php' and 'single-{your-post-type}.php'.. my question is about custom taxonomy archive page. instead of archive.php

Comment: you never mentioned taxonomy on your question, you'd have to use ```taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php``` or ```taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php```

Comment: I edited my answer, checkout https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/

Comment: currently all 4 custom post type use archive.php for taxonomy.. i want to add 4 separate archive template

Comment: i have 15 categories and multiple subcateogy in each CPT. this way is not short.. is there anyway for all CPT taxonomy archive??? As we use stranded in archive.php

Answer (score 0):

lets say you have custom post types (CTP).. cpt1, cpt2, cpt3 ...

then you just need to create archive templates files respectively like that 
**archive-cpt1.php** , **archive-cpt2.php** , **archive-cpt3.php** .

Comment: That's for creating an archive for custom post types, the question was about creating custom post type taxonomy archive.